# How to POST xml data through RestTemplate in the body of request?

Tags: java, xml, string, resttemplate

I am using RestTemplate to execute an URL. The url takes an input parameter which is in XML format.

I have a XML like this which is stored as a String in `xmlData` variable and I need to pass this String to my url in `client_data` variable -

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ClientData
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.google.com model.xsd" 
 xmlns="http://www.google.com"> 
    <client id="100">
        <clock>
                <for>
                    <etc>val(tery) = 1</etc>
                    <while><![CDATA[val(tery)  < 20]]></while>
                </for>
        </clock>
    </model>
</ClientData>
```

Below is the code I have -

```
String xmlData = getXMLData(); // this will return me above XML data as it is in String format
String url = generateURL(xmlData);

// but this line is returning me bad request always in exception
String response = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);
```

Below is how my `url` is looking like after generating it and `RestTemplate` internally does the URL encoding as per my understanding then why I am still seeing the bad request?

```
http://localhost:8080/test_tmp?client_data=<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ClientData
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.google.com model.xsd" 
 xmlns="http://www.google.com"> 
    <client id="100">
        <clock>
                <for>
                    <etc>val(tery) = 1</etc>
                    <while><![CDATA[val(tery)  < 20]]></while>
                </for>
        </clock>
    </model>
</ClientData>
```

If I url encode the XML string manually and hit the url through the browser then it works fine. What wrong I am doing here?

Comment: Such data really has its place in POST data, not as a query parameter. URIs have a limited length, you may well hit the limit with this system.

Comment: @fge I see your point, since my XML might get bigger so you are right in that regards. So how do I use POST with RestTemplate then?

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#postForObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object...-

Comment: @fge, Can you provide an example how do I use exchange method  of `RestTemplate` here? I went through this [tutorial](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html#rest-resttemplate) but didn't find any examples related to that.

Comment: @fge I also have updated the question with the solution I have tried but it gives bad request error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is RestTemplate is doing the url encoding and that is causing the problem. The method that accepts URL as String assumes it is not encoded and hence it encodes it for you. You can check the variants over here: [Working with the URI](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html#rest-resttemplate-uri).Hunch is it is encoding your endpoint to an unreachable one.

What we need to do is prevent it from encoding automatically. We can do this by using the method that takes **URI** instead of String for url.

The sample below shows how we could encode the XML data string and pass it using RestTemplate without allowing RestTemplate to do the encoding:

```
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("http://localhost:8080/test_tmp");
    builder.append("?max_time=30&users=1000&client_data=");
    builder.append(URLEncoder.encode(xmlData));

    URI uri = URI.create(builder.toString());

    restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. RestTemplate will do the url encoding for you internally so you don't need to do it manually, otherwise it will do it twice. I tried it just now in any case, it gives me back same Bad Request exception. Also, as fge suggested out, it is better to use POST to send XML since my XML might grow bigger and URI have limited length.

Comment: Okay if you are doing POST ensure your rest service has one to accept POST calls // example: @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)

Comment: let me try setting the header correctly since I don't want to modify the code to accept form submissions.

Comment: Try with MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA and MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED

Comment: So it should be like this `HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
requestHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(requestHeaders);
String response = restTemplate.postForObject(url, entity, String.class);` right?

Comment: No. Do all the steps(of code part) in my answer excepting the last part(Lastly change the endpoint so that it consumes form data - skip this). Play with the setContentType - first try with MULTIPART. If that doesnt work try APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED.

Comment: I hope you are doing good. I got stuck again on another `RestTemplate` question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28390662/how-to-execute-the-complicated-url-through-resttemplate). Now I have very complicated URL, not sure how can I execute it through `RestTemplate`. If possible can you help me out?

Comment: are you still around?

Comment: A bit busy and very late tonight. Will check your problem tomorrow.